# React callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can someone explain to me please why this code works

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
```

but if remove the arrow function in the elements onClick value

```
renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
```

it gives me the error Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.%s

The full code can be found here https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/KmmrBy?editors=0010

Comment: You're executing the function, you're not passing it to `onClick`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the second example... You must use an double arrow function.. Because every time you render that component you will execute `this.handleClick(i)` that leads you to an infinite execution of that function, to avoid this behavior use the double arrow function:

```
const handleClick = i => e => {
    // do anything with i here ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` require a function, in the first example, you passed the function (arrow function), but the second example, it's not a function.
another way

```
renderSquare(i) {
 return (
  <Square
    value={this.state.squares[i]}
    onClick={function(){
      this.handleClick(i)
    }}
  />
);
```

}